# String split and preserve the contents inside the quotation " " - Python

Tags: python-3.x

I wanted to split a list. But After equal to symbol, I will always have " ". I wanted the split function not to split the content inside this quotation.

```
my_string =''<gpxd:Address AddressLanguage="eng" ISO="TR" Country="XYZ" City="ADENA" Street="CEYHAN YLLU PUTERI " HouseNo="5.KM POLIS GANGAI KARŞISI YÜßÜĞpp" ZIP="70310"/>\n''
```

If I use `my_string.split(" ")`, it also splits the entire content. But I wanted the contents in between the " " not to be splitted. 
Expected Output:

```
''<gpxd:Address AddressLanguage="eng"', 'ISO="TR"', 'Country="XYZ"', 'City="ADENA"', 'Street="CEYHAN YLLU PUTERI', '" HouseNo="5.KM POLIS GANGAI KARŞISI YÜßÜĞpp"', 'ZIP="70310"', />\n'
```

ANy help would be apreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's XML, so why not use Python's XML parser?

```
>>> from xml.etree.ElementTree import fromstring
>>> my_string = '<Address AddressLanguage="eng" ISO="TR" Country="XYZ" City="ADENA" Street="CEYHAN YLLU PUTERI " HouseNo="5.KM POLIS GANGAI KARŞISI YÜßÜĞpp" ZIP="70310"/>\n'
>>> xml = fromstring(my_string)
>>> xml.tag
'Address'
>>> xml.attrib
{'City': 'ADENA', 'HouseNo': '5.KM POLIS GANGAI KARŞISI YÜßÜĞpp', 'ISO': 'TR', 'Street': 'CEYHAN YLLU PUTERI ', 'AddressLanguage': 'eng', 'Country': 'XYZ', 'ZIP': '70310'}
```

Note that I had to remove the namespace prefix (`gpxd:`) from the string in order for `fromstring()` to parse it properly. There are a variety of ways to handle that situation... I'll leave it up to you to figure out what makes most sense in your sitation. See the [ElementTree documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) for more info.